# Simplest way to repeat every N rows in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I know this is possible through some complex techniques, i want to know any simplest way to achieve this patter that every 10 rows should repeat .
for example

```
        select a,b from tablename; (repeating 2 for example)
```

will give

```
        a1,b1     
        a2,b2
        a1,b1  
        a2.b2
        a3,b3
        a4,b4
        a3,b3
        a4,b4
```

where if it was 10 it will go like

```
    a1,b1 to a10,b10 again a1,b1 to a10,b10
```

then

```
    a11,b11 to a20,b20 again a11,b11 to a20,b20
```

and so on

Comment: make your expected output clear

Comment: Your output rows seem somehow "interleaved". Is that intensional ? Anyway, please remember than without a proper `ORDER BY` clause, your table should be considered as an _unordered set_.

Comment: Just use a cartesian join with a row generator.

Comment: i want every set of 10 rows to be repeated twice

Comment: Se emy update in answer, it is exactly what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want blocks of ten rows repeated twice. So to get:

```
rows 1 to 10
rows 1 to 10
rows 11 to 20
rows 11 to 20
...
```

In order to get rows n-fold cross join with a table holding n records. (You get such for instance by querying a big enough table and stop at rowcount n.)

You also need the row number of your original records, so you can get block 1 first, then block 2 and so on. Use integer division to get from row numbers to blocks.

```
select t.a, t.b
from (select a, b, row_number() over (order by a, b) as rn from tablename) t
cross join (select rownum as repeatno from bigenoughtable where rownum <= 2) r
order by trunc((t.rn -1) / 10), r.repeatno, t.a, t.b;
```

Comment: Sorry, I confused integer division and modulo. I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use a CTE and union all:

```
with rows as (
      select a, b
      from tablename
      where rownum <= 2
     )
select *
from rows
union all
select *
from rows;
```

Just some caveats to this.  You should use an `order by` if you want particular rows from the table.  This is important, because the same select can return different sets of rows.  Actually, considering this, a better way is probably:

```
with rows as (
      select a, b
      from tablename
      where rownum <= 2
     )
select *
from rows cross join
     (select 1 as n from dual union all select 2 from dual) n;
```

Comment: this will repeat only once a1,a2,a1,a2
what about a1,a2,a1,a2,a3,a4,a3,a4 type.

Comment: such that every n rows repeat twice

Comment: @siddharthgupta . . . That is what your question asks.  The second query clearly generalizes to more repeating groups.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather not use `UNION` so many times. My way would be `CONNECT BY ROWNUM <=N`. Actually a `CARTESIAN JOIN`. So, basically you need a ROW GENERATOR to cartesian join with it.,

**Update**

For example, this will repeat 10 rows 2 times -

```
SQL> WITH t AS
  2    ( SELECT 'a1' A, 'b1' b FROM dual
  3    UNION ALL
  4    SELECT 'a2' a, 'b2' b FROM dual
  5    UNION ALL
  6    SELECT 'a3' a, 'b3' b FROM dual
  7    UNION ALL
  8    SELECT 'a4' A, 'b4' b FROM dual
  9    UNION ALL
 10    SELECT 'a5' A, 'b5' b FROM dual
 11    UNION ALL
 12    SELECT 'a6' a, 'b6' b FROM dual
 13    UNION ALL
 14    SELECT 'a7' A, 'b7' b FROM dual
 15    UNION ALL
 16    SELECT 'a8' a, 'b8' b FROM dual
 17    UNION ALL
 18    SELECT 'a9' a, 'b9' b FROM dual
 19    UNION ALL
 20    SELECT 'a10' a, 'b10' b FROM dual
 21    )
 22  SELECT A,B FROM t,
 23    (SELECT 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM <=2
 24    )
 25    /

A   B
--- ---
a1  b1
a2  b2
a3  b3
a4  b4
a5  b5
a6  b6
a7  b7
a8  b8
a9  b9
a10 b10
a1  b1
a2  b2
a3  b3
a4  b4
a5  b5
a6  b6
a7  b7
a8  b8
a9  b9
a10 b10

20 rows selected.

SQL>
```

So, above `CONNECT BY ROWNUM <=10` means repeat the rows 10 times. If you want it to be repeated N times use `CONNECT BY ROWNUM <=N`.

Comment: this will repeat a single row 10 times, i want a set of 10 rows to be repeated twice

Comment: In my example, there are only 2 rows, so 2 rows repeated 10 times. All you need is have 10 rows from your table and repeat it two times. See my update.

Comment: yeah this is what i want , but it should continue further like after 20 rows a11,b11 to a20,b20 repeated 2 times then a21 to a30 repeated 2 times again.

Comment: Now you know what to do, play around with it.